# Metadata enable-os-login prohibiting RDP connections?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When setting up a Windows VM instance (Windows 2016 DataCenter) in google cloud's Compute Engine, I noticed that a metadata item of "enable-os-login" is set to true.

[image]

However, when I try to connect via RDP to the Windows instance, it returns an error and I cannot connect. External IP address and appropriate firewall for RDP port 3389 are set correctly.

[image]

When removing the metadata item, RDP connections will work again. Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 0):

OS Login is a feature not supported by Windows.
OS Login is mainly used for Linux VM instances to manage SSH access whereas Windows VM Instances uses RDP and is a [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/set-up-oslogin#limitations) of the feature.

Comment: Strange that it has this negative impact on Windows then. Thx.